# How to create a responsive table with bootstrap with multiple layers of sub columns?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Below is an example of a table I want to create using bootstrap.

```
  _______________________________________________________________
  |   Col1        |        Col2        |         Col3           |
  |  Scol1  SCol2 |  Scol1  SCol2      |  Scol1  SCol2  SCol3   |
  --------------------------------------------------------------|
  |  data   data  |   data   data      |  data   data    data   |
  ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have included a jsfiddle with an example of this http://jsfiddle.net/tester123/muofm3zb/

Comment: What seems to be a problem? Bootstrap directly supports [nested columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting).

Comment: Please be specific about your question, You haven't tried anything yet. Read the docs!

Comment: The problem I am having is that the table i need to generate needs more than the max 12 columns that the default bootstrap grid provides. Is there a way to increase this number of columns?